# How should my WebAPI access other APIs exposed by other Tenants in Microsoft Identity Platform into my app?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2b, microsoft-identity-platform

I have a "hub and spoke" model for a single ASP.NET Core website, and several "spoke APIs" that are located in N other AzureAD tenants.

[image]

... which calls API Apps located in other tenants ...

[image]

My goal is to have this "hub" website use incremental consent with external partners that align with the scenario: [Protected AzureAD API calling another Protected API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-api-call-api-overview).  The key difference in my situation is that the second API is located in another tenant, managed by another administrator whom I don't know. (should I beware of dragons? If so what are they?)

Since I need to use the On-Behalf-Of flow to access these external websites, the website becomes a trusted client. The AAD samples include only Desktop and SPA trusted client apps for this scenario ([sample1](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore-v2/tree/master/2.%20Web%20API%20now%20calls%20Microsoft%20Graph), [sample2](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-aspnet-webapi-onbehalfof))

**Question**

1. Is this a supported scenario? (Tenants offering services to other Tenants)
2. What is the preferred way to share API Scopes, Permissions, and other GUID/Identifiers?
3. In the v2 Endpoint, are both Personal and AAD accounts supported?
4. How would I translate Tenant GUIDs for scopes and other contents in the app Manifest into a display name?

Comment: This is supported. If you check your sample 2 link, the OBO is happening to a Web API that you dont own (MS Graph). I would recommend reading that sample `readme.md` so you can understand the concepts of **knownClienApplications** and  **/.default scope**.

Comment: You should ask one question in one post. Your other questions are not clear, can you post a new one?

Comment: Did you try this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-expose-web-apis . It is possible to configure an external application id(client ID) to access a Web APi across tenants.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a supported scenario? (Tenants offering services to other
>   Tenants)

Yes, this is supported. If you are have a webapi in A tenant(webapi A), and want to access webapi in B tenant(webapi B must be multi-tenant application), the webapi B must exist in A tenant under Enterprise applications(Someone in A tenant ever logged in webapi B).

> In the v2 Endpoint, are both Personal and AAD accounts supported?

Yes, V2 endpoint supports both Personal and AAD accounts.